# compare object filter on filename instead of hash value

Tags: powershell, hash

I'm using a script that moves files from our local storage to our central storage.

After it's placed on the central storage i'm doing a comparation between local and central to make sure everything got placed there correctly. 
Whenever something goes wrong i get the hash value of the file instead of the file itself. 
Obviously for my end users it would be much more usefull if the file itself where something was wrong with was in the mail instead of a hash value.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (dir $nas_smb_share -Recurse | Where-object{(!$_.psiscontainer) } | get-hash)  -differenceObject (dir $cs_dest -Recurse  | Where-object{(!$_.psiscontainer) -AND ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1))} | get-hash)  -Property Name -PassThru |
%{if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" ){$result = ("$($_.InputObject)")}}
```

here i'm  using the result from the compare-object, using it to get the file, but i don't manage to get the actual file as result instead of the hash value. 
Probably has something to do with the -Property Name Passtru?

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result)){$res = "Transfer succeeded without problems"}
else {
$hash_error = 1
$res = ("transfer failed on following file(s): "+ (dir $cs_dest -Recurse  | 
Where-Object {(!$_.psiscontainer)} | get-hash | ? {$_.hashstring -match 
$result}) )
}
```

thanks allready for any input.

note: the files being moved are forensic images which are divided in parts about 1,5Gb in size. So the data isn't readable in any way unless you have all parts there.

Comment: How about a change in logic? On local storage, calculate a hash and save it to separate file. With a pair of files like `image1.iso` and `image1.iso.local.sha1` you have the data and hash. Copy the data, recalculate and save the hash as `image1.iso.central.sha1` and compare the hashes. If they don't match, you can trivially parse file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be misreading what you're asking here - but I have some code I use to copy files across servers and confirm it was copied successfully, and it looks like it should fit your use case at least.

```
$TimeSince = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
Get-ChildItem "LocalDrive" | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $TimeSince} | % {
    #Details of both local and remote files, this is run from local storage.
    $LocalFile = $_.FullName
    $RemoteFile = Join-Path "RemoteDrive" $_.Name

    #Copy file to remote directory if it doesn't exist - sounds like you can remove this part.
    if (!(Test-Path $RemoteFile)){
        Write-Host "Copying '$($LocalFile)' -> '$($RemoteFile)'" -Fore Yellow
        Copy-Item $LocalFile $RemoteFile
    }

    #Calculate both hashes and do a normal compare inside an IF, output can easily be changed.
    $LocalHash = Get-FileHash $LocalFile -Algorithm MD5
    $RemoteHash = Get-FileHash $RemoteFile -Algorithm MD5

    if ($LocalHash.Hash -ne $RemoteHash.Hash){
        Write-Host "Mismatch with '$($_.Name)'" -Fore Red
    }
}
```

My original script has some more error handling but it's all very general.

Just as a note - if you're using compare object, the 'results' it returns are limited to what it's comparing - you'll need to keep a separate track of 'display' values if you wish to use alternate ones.

Comment: well your script looks promising to say the least.
I'm using the script now to sync multiple folders/files towards the central storage. Do you have any idea about the performance of the Get-childItem vs the Compare Object?

Comment: @Michael `Get-ChildItem` is actually just the `true` name of `dir` - this only calls `dir` once and the remaining calls (aside from `Get-FileHash`) are all done in-memory, so it should have a reasonable performance advantage over your existing script, i'd imagine the bottleneck will be running `Get-FileHash` on the remote files, you could get around this by using `Invoke-Command` - but it's probably not worth the effort unless this is a very large-scale copy operation.

Comment: @Michael you can test both by wrapping them inside `Measure-Command { ... }` and it will tell you how long it took - I imagine 90% of the script won't be spent listing the files though, so there may not be any significant time difference.

Comment: how would i go about adding the $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) command to exclude files older then 1 hour in the hash calculation. 

This to avoid having files 2 weeks old also getting their hash still compared?

Comment: @Michael I just added it on the initial `Get-ChildItem` there - this will exclude on the local side, if you're looking to overwrite old files or exclude them, it'll be an extra bit of logic to check both sides before performing copies or comparisons.